# How to make user logout ,when he try to enter register URL?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm trying to make when user is logged in, and enters url for registration, to be logged out and show registration form.

In my controller method for registration I added this but it's not working:

```
 public function register()
 {
        if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')) {
            $this->session->sess_destroy();
            redirect('auth/logout');
        }
        //form validation
        if ($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE)
        {
            $this->signup();
        }
        else 
        {  
          //login
        }
  }

  public function signup()
  {

        $data['dynamic_view'] = 'auth/register_form';
        $this->load->view('templates/main',$data);  
  }
```

My login method is

```
 public function login ()
    {

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'username', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'trim|required'); 


        if ($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE)
        {

            $this->index();
        }
        else 
        {
            if ($user = $this->auth_model->login()) {
                if(count($user) > 0 )    
                {
                    $this->load->library('session'); 

                     $data = array(
                        'username' => $user['username'],
                        'user_id' => $user['user_id'],
                        'is_logged_in' => TRUE

                    );
                    $this->session->set_userdata($data);         

                    redirect('home');
                }
            }
            else
            {   

                 $this->index();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: When user is logged in my application and when he logout from it. It doesn't have to be in his profile when he enters URL for registration. I want to logout from his profile and show registration form. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$this->session->unset_userdata('is_logged_in');`, no need to destroy whole session.  I would do something else in such case, I would just redirect to main page and set flashdata message.

Also there could be a problem with loading library. Try to add session library to autoload.php in application/config.

Answer (score 1):

inside your `public function register()`, if you redirect to another page with `redirect('auth/logout');`, the rest of the script will never get executed. `$this->session->sess_destroy();` should be enough to disconnect the user.